# Keyboard hide leaves empty blank space

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an issue like after my keyboard pops up and hides there is an empty space where ever the keyboard was. I have nothing but few components inside `ScrollView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/state"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_state" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/district"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_district" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/police_station"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_station" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_type"
        layout="@layout/template_cascading_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_manufacturer"
        layout="@layout/template_cascading_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_model"
        layout="@layout/template_cascading_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/registration_no"
        layout="@layout/template_registration_no"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/engine_no"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_station" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/chassis_no"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_station" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/capture_image"
        layout="@layout/template_image_control"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And ScreenShot of it.

[image]

I didn't find any reason yet why this is happening. Any Help will be helpful.

**NOTE :**
I Googled enough to find the solutions, adding the `windowBackground` in `styles.xml` didn't help. And I don't find valid reason to use that.

I also tried without adding `TextInputLayout`. But the result was same.

Happening in all versions of Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out after breaking my head. This was happening due to `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` which I used in activity.

The above `xml` is a fragment attached to the `MainActivity`. In Main Activity XML I have `CoordinateLayout` as parent. I think there might be some bug with using `CoordinateLayout` along with `ScrollView`.

Changing it to `LinearLayout` fixed my issue for now.

Comment: Thank you very much! Happened to me with `ScrollView` inside `ConstraintLayout`. Changing `ConstraintLayout` to `LinearLayout` immediately solved it.